# Difference between UIWebView Fontsize and UItextView Fontsize

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview, uitextview

Can any one tell me what is the major difference between UIWebView's font size property and UITextView's FontSize property??

Both are different, As UIWebView's Fontsize is very bigger then UITextView's font size, through both are 15..

Please tell me, What is the difference?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following is working properly.

```
<html><body style="margin-top:0px; margin-left:0px"><marquee behavior="alternate" style="font-family:verdana;font-size:10px; color:red;">Test</marquee></font></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

although both are rendering HTML but main difference is,

**UIWebView** giving u the HTML view its font size denpend **ViewPort**,

where as the **UITextView** can control its **font size**.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official Objective C [website](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html):

"This class does not support multiple styles for text. The font, color, and text alignment attributes you specify always apply to the entire contents of the text view. To display more complex styling in your application, you need to use a UIWebView object and render your content using HTML."

How I understood it: on a UIVewView you can use as text HTML tags, in UITextView it will be displayed as a plain text. The UIWebView's font's size depends from the ViewPort, and you have no direct access to it, as well as the UITextView has properties for the font size setup.